# fail to create propper habtm scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I stuck (.I have two models with habtm relationship.

```
  create_table "daily_menus", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "day"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.date     "date"
  end

  add_index "daily_menus", ["day"], name: "index_daily_menus_on_day", unique: true, using: :btree

  create_table "daily_menus_dishes", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "daily_menu_id"
    t.integer "dish_id"
  end

  add_index "daily_menus_dishes", ["daily_menu_id", "dish_id"], name: "index_daily_menus_dishes_on_daily_menu_id_and_dish_id", using: :btree

  create_table "dish_types", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "meal"
  end

  create_table "dishes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "dish_type_id"
  end

  add_index "dishes", ["dish_type_id", "name"], name: "index_dishes_on_dish_type_id_and_name", unique: true, using: :btree
```

And also a table of dish_type with relation to dishes has_many :dishes. What I need is a scope where all dishes with specified type would be included except those that are already in menu. Im fighting with this problem for the second day. Need some help. Here are my last failure attepts

```
  #scope :menu_available, -> (type_id, daily_menu_id){ where('dish_type_id = ?', type_id) & where(joins(:daily_menus).where.not('daily_menu_id = ?', daily_menu_id)) }

  #scope :menu_available, lambda { |type_id, daily_menu_id| joins(:daily_menus).where('dishes.dish_type_id = ? AND daily_menus.id != ?', type_id, daily_menu_id) }
  #scope :menu_available, lambda { |daily_menu_id| joins(:daily_menus).where('daily_menus.id is NULL AND daily_menus.id != ?', daily_menu_id) }
  scope :menu_available,  -> { joins(:daily_menus).where(daily_menus: { id: 17 }) }
  scope :menu_available, -> { where("dish_type_id = ?", 14).joins(:daily_menus).where("daily_menu_id != ?", 17)}
```

I have a small success, now it finds all dishes that are not included in menu

```
scope :without_menu, -> { joins('LEFT JOIN daily_menus_dishes ON dishes.id = daily_menus_dishes.dish_id').where('daily_menus_dishes.daily_menu_id is NULL')}
```

some bigger success!!

```
scope :without_menu, -> { joins('LEFT JOIN daily_menus_dishes ON dishes.id = daily_menus_dishes.dish_id').where('daily_menus_dishes.daily_menu_id is NULL OR daily_menus_dishes.daily_menu_id != ?', 14) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what I got, may be it can be refactored?

```
 scope :without_menu, -> { joins('LEFT JOIN daily_menus_dishes ON dishes.id = daily_menus_dishes.dish_id').where('daily_menus_dishes.daily_menu_id is NULL OR daily_menus_dishes.daily_menu_id != ?', 14).where(dish_type: 14).order('name ASC') }
```